# Loopback Client Side Authentication Check

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

Is there an out of the box way to do a client-side authentication check using the standard Loopback authentication/user model?  I don't want to rely on the client side checks alone, but for something as simple as showing a "logout" button when a user is logged in it would be useful to check this on the client side.

I'm really looking to modify the DOM in Angular based on the response of an isAuthenticated function or something similar.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an isAuthenticated function in the Loopback Angular SDK.  Referenced here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular/blob/fb161b7eaa02df877fe894daa54e4bd0fa4e041e/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If the user has logged in, then you would have received an access token back in the response, which you use for all future API calls. If you have a token, then they are authenticated. If you aren't sure if it's a valid token you could just try to hit `/User/[id]?access_token=[token]` - if that fails, they are not authenticated any longer.